# How to find the most frequent value from multiple columns in a dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe

I have data frame as follows :

```
S A B C D E 
1 N N N N N
2 N Y Y N N
3 Y N Y N N
4 Y N Y Y Y
```

where do I need to create a new column F which contains the most occurrences character from the multiple columns A, B, C, D, and E?

The output should look like the following :

```
 S A B C D E F
 1 N N N N N N
 2 N Y Y N N N
 3 Y N Y N N N
 4 Y N Y Y Y Y
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We can create a `Mode` function and apply over the rows

```
df1$F <- apply(df1[-1], 1, Mode)
df1
#  S A B C D E F
#1 1 N N N N N N
#2 2 N Y Y N N N
#3 3 Y N Y N N N
#4 4 Y N Y Y Y Y
```

---

Or another option is

```
df1$F <- c('N', 'Y')[max.col(table(c(row(df1[-1])), unlist(df1[-1])), 'first')]
```

where

```
Mode <- function(x) {
 ux <- unique(x)
 ux[which.max(tabulate(match(x, ux)))]
}
```

---

Or using `tidyverse`

```
library(tidyverse)
df1 %>% 
    mutate(F = pmap_chr(.[-1], ~ Mode(c(...))))
```

---

Or another option is

```
gather(df1, key, F, - S) %>% 
     group_by(S, F) %>% 
     summarise(n = n()) %>% 
     slice(which.max(n)) %>% 
     ungroup %>% 
     dplyr::select(F) %>% 
     bind_cols(df1, .)
```

---

Or we transpose the dataset, apply the `Mode` by each column and then bind the output as new column to original dataset

```
t(df1[-1]) %>%
   as.data.frame %>% 
   summarise_all(Mode) %>% 
   unlist %>%
   bind_cols(df1, F = .)
```

---

Or an option with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[,  F := names(which.max(table(unlist(.SD)))), S][]
```

NOTE: These are general methods instead of just checking on a single case

---

If we need an efficient method, without any `ifelse`, we can also do this by

```
df1$F <- c("Y", "N")[(rowSums(df1[-1] == "N") > 2) + 1]
df1$F
#[1] "N" "N" "N" "Y"
```

Or with `Reduce`

```
c("Y", "N")[(Reduce(`+`, lapply(df1[-1], `==`, "N")) > 2) + 1]
```

Or another approach is

```
c("Y", "N")[(str_count(do.call(paste0, df1[-1]), "N") > 2) + 1]
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(S = 1:4, A = c("N", "N", "Y", "Y"), B = c("N", 
"Y", "N", "N"), C = c("N", "Y", "Y", "Y"), D = c("N", "N", "N", 
"Y"), E = c("N", "N", "N", "Y")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))
```

Answer (score 3):

One `dplyr` possibility could be:

```
df %>%
 mutate(F = ifelse(rowSums(.[2:length(.)] == "N") > 2, "N", "Y"))

  S A B C D E F
1 1 N N N N N N
2 2 N Y Y N N N
3 3 Y N Y N N N
4 4 Y N Y Y Y Y
```

It assumes that there are just `N` and `Y` values and that the number of columns is 5.

As @Sotos noted, it could be easily rewritten to `base R` form:

```
df$F <- ifelse(rowSums(df[2:length(df)] == "N") > 2, "N", "Y")
```

Or without the assumption about the number of columns (based on @TinglTanglBob):

```
df %>%
 mutate(F = ifelse(rowMeans(.[2:length(.)] == "N") > 0.5, "N", "Y"))
```

The same with base R:

```
df$F <- ifelse(rowMeans(df[2:length(df)] == "N") > 0.5, "N", "Y")
```

Comment: +1 Great idea, avoiding the `apply()` with margin `1`. It could have been way better If you did not load `dplyr` just for the pipe and `mutate`. Just leave it in base R. In addition, you could also make `2` dynamic. Something like `ceiling(ncol(df) / 2)`

Comment: you could use rowMeans(...) >0.5 to avoid making an assumption about the number of columns

Answer (score 2):

An alternative, slightly different:

```r
x$F <- unlist(do.call(Map, c(function(...) names(sort(-table(c(...)), partial=1)[1]), x[,-1])))
x
#   S A B C D E F
# 1 1 N N N N N N
# 2 2 N Y Y N N N
# 3 3 Y N Y N N N
# 4 4 Y N Y Y Y Y
```

Perhaps I'm just trying to produce obscure code now ...

I'm realizing this might be more general than absolutely necessary. This finds the most frequent "thing" regardless of how many different things exist among the rows.

The `sort(..., partial=1)` stops sorting after the first pass.

Answer (score 1):

Or:

```
d <- read.table(text ="S A B C D E 
1 N N N N N
2 N Y Y N N
3 Y N Y N N
4 Y N Y Y Y", header = TRUE, row.names = 1, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

d$F <- with(
  stack(data.frame(t(as.matrix(d)), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)),
  tapply(values, ind, function(x) names(sort(table(x), decreasing = TRUE)[1])))
d

#A B C D E F
#1 N N N N N N
#2 N Y Y N N N
#3 Y N Y N N N
#4 Y N Y Y Y Y
```